# JS callback with iterating over array doesn't work

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm having issues with this JS script because of good old Mr.Async who doesn't like me.

Even though tocsv function supposes to wait for a callback with csvdata, the csv is being created before the callback and I get an empty file.

I would really appreciate your help with understanding how to solve this

```js
tocsv(sites,createcsv); 

// ITEREATE OVER FILE SITES.JS
function tocsv(urls, callback) {
 for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var theurl = urls[i];

  getData(theurl, function(the_page_title) {
   csvdata.push([the_page_title]);
  });
 };
 callback(csvdata);
};

// Get title from url
function getData(url, callback) {
 csvdata = [];
 
 $.get(url, function(data){

   $("title", data).each(function() {
      
      the_page_title = $(this).text();
      });
 
    callback(the_page_title);
    });
};
 
function createcsv(thedata) {
 var data = thedata;
 console.log(data);
 var csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
 data.forEach(function(infoArray, index){

    dataString = infoArray.join(",");
    csvContent += index < data.length ? dataString+ "\n" : dataString;

 }); 

 var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
 var link = document.createElement("a");
 link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
 link.setAttribute("download", "my_data.csv");
 document.body.appendChild(link); // Required for FF

 link.click(); // This will download the data file named "my_data.csv". 
}
```

Comment: `$.get` is **asynchronous**. Your `tocsv` function can't directly call `callback` with the data, because `tocsv` returns before the data is available.

Comment: `csvdata.push([the_page_title]);` Did you really mean to push an *array* into the `csvdata` array? Not just an entry?

Comment: Your code is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) in multiple places. Be sure to declare your variables, in the narrowest possible scope.

Comment: that's why i added the callback

Comment: @T.J. Crowder yes I will add more args to the csv later

Comment: Adding a callback doesn't magically make your code call it at the right time. Also, what's up with the `$.each("title", ...)` thing? Are there really multiple titles? Are you trying to collect them all together? Your current code just takes the last last one.

Comment: there is only one title in a url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
var csvdata = [];
tocsv(sites, createcsv);

// ITEREATE OVER FILE SITES.JS
function tocsv(urls, callback) {
    var count = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var theurl = urls[i];

        getData(theurl, function(the_page_title) {
            count++;
            csvdata.push([the_page_title]);
            if(count == 3) {
                callback(csvdata);
            }
        });
    };
};

// Get title from url
function getData(url, callback) {

    $.get(url, function(data) {

        $("title", data).each(function() {

            the_page_title = $(this).text();
        });

        callback(the_page_title);
    });
};

function createcsv(thedata) {
    var data = thedata;
    console.log(data);
    var csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
    data.forEach(function(infoArray, index) {

        dataString = infoArray.join(",");
        csvContent += index < data.length ? dataString + "\n" : dataString;

    });

    var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
    link.setAttribute("download", "my_data.csv");
    document.body.appendChild(link); // Required for FF

    link.click(); // This will download the data file named "my_data.csv".  
}
```